# Unable to get multiple featured images wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I have used multiple featured images plugin.

using : [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-featured-images/#installation)

I have followed the instructions give on this page.

I want to show images in the page below header. Adding this below code in header.php, images appear above page header.

```
 <?php
        kdmfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'full' );
        kdmfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-3', 'full' );
    ?>
```

Can anyone tell me where should i add this line in single.php in proper way?

**EDIT :**

**single.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area col-sm-12 col-md-8">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <?php
                kdmfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'full' );
                kdmfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-3', 'full' );
             ?>
        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
            the_post_navigation();
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

        <?php

            kdmfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'full' );

         ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

**header.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <header id="masthead" class="cvit-page-header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only"><?php echo esc_html__('Toggle navigation', 'wp-bootstrap-starter'); ?></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <?php if(has_header_image()) :?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>" class="site-logo"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr(get_custom_header()->height); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr(get_custom_header()->width); ?>" alt="<?php esc_url(bloginfo('name')); ?>" /></a>
                   <?php else: ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>"><?php echo('Technologies'); ?></a><br>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  </div>
                </div>

                    <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <div class="header-content">
                            <?php
                                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                                            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                                            'depth'             => 3,
                                            'container'         => '',
                                            'container_class'   => '',
                                            'container_id'      => 'navbar-collapsed',
                                            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                    );
                            ?>
                            <div class="navbar-right" role="navigation">
                                <a href="http://wp-test.dev/products/" class="btn btn-blue">PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <section id="content" class="site-content cvit-page-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <?php
                kdmfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'full' );
                kdmfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-3', 'full' );
             ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
   <?php
 add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
 function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
$items .= '<li class=”searchbox-position”>' . get_search_form( false ) . '</li>';
return $items;
 }

if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_setup' ) ) :

function wp_bootstrap_starter_setup() {

    load_theme_textdomain( 'wp-bootstrap-starter', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
    add_theme_support('html5', array('search-form'));

    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    //For registration of a new featured image please use the handy filter
    add_filter( 'kdmfi_featured_images', function( $featured_images ) {
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'featured-image-2',
        'desc' => 'Your description here.',
        'label_name' => 'Featured Image 2',
        'label_set' => 'Set featured image 2',
        'label_remove' => 'Remove featured image 2',
        'label_use' => 'Set featured image 2',
        'post_type' => array( 'page' ),
    );

    $featured_images[] = $args;

    return $featured_images;
});

add_filter( 'kdmfi_featured_images', function( $featured_images ) {

    $args = array(
        'id' => 'featured-image-3',
        'desc' => 'Your description here.',
        'label_name' => 'Featured Image 3',
        'label_set' => 'Set featured image 3',
        'label_remove' => 'Remove featured image 3',
        'label_use' => 'Set featured image 3',
        'post_type' => array( 'page' ),
    );

    $featured_images[] = $args;

    return $featured_images;
});

    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'wp-bootstrap-starter' ),
    ) );

    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'comment-form',
        'comment-list',
        'gallery',
        'caption',
    ) );

    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_custom_background_args', array(
        'default-color' => 'ffffff',
        'default-image' => '',
    ) ) );

    add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );

}
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wp_bootstrap_starter_setup' );

function wp_bootstrap_starter_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_content_width', 1170 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wp_bootstrap_starter_content_width', 0 );


function wp_bootstrap_starter_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'wp-bootstrap-starter' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'wp-bootstrap-starter' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wp_bootstrap_starter_widgets_init' );

function wp_bootstrap_starter_scripts() {

 wp_enqueue_style( 'default', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/stylesheets/default.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'html5hiv',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/html5.js', array(), '3.7.0', false );
    wp_script_add_data( 'html5hiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', array() );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js', array() );


    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_bootstrap_starter_scripts' );

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/extras.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';

if ( ! class_exists( 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker' )) {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/inc/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see your code to be able to help with placement.

Comment: i have added the code from https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-featured-images/#installation in functions.php

Comment: That is not YOUR code, that is the plugin code, which is handy but we also need your own. AKA the code from the site you're using the plugin on.

Comment: @PhillHealey  I have added code.

Comment: your code is working fine for me

Comment: Can you give us the link to the page where you are using this code and facing this issue?

Comment: @vel , code is working. I want to display images in single.php not in header.php Images are being displayed in only header.php not in single.php

Comment: @Shweta, single.php file is for single post not for single page. so you cannot get feature image in single.php. Post doesnt has feature image that is the issue.

Comment: And if you want to get the featured image of a post put yhat code after while loop in single.php